# Morpheme 'li' in friendliness

Tags: morphemes

In class today the word 'friendliness' was split up into three morphemes rather than my prefered two.

I don't understand why 'li' has claim to be a morpheme rather than 'liness', which seems to be very productive.

Comment: The _-li_ in _friendliness_ ***is*** the _-ly_ of _friendly_. It's just a different spelling. And that's what it means: [[friend + -li] + -ness] -- the property of being friendly.

Answer (score 6):

[*ly*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ly) is a morpheme that can be appended to most nouns to mean "like", so *saintly* means "like a saint". This turns the noun into an adjective.

[*ness*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-ness?s=t) is another morpheme that can be appended to an adjective, to create a noun describing that abstract property, e.g. "dark" => "darkness". When the adjective ends with **y**, it's usually changed to **i**, e.g. *happiness* (in general, we don't use the vowel form of "y" in the middle of words, and replace it with "i").

*friendliness* appends each of these morphemes separately: "friend" (noun) => "friendly" (adjective) => "friendliness" (abstract property noun)

It's common to use *liness* together, but that doesn't make it a single morpheme; the meaning of each morpheme doesn't change when they're combined this way.

Comment: Good, clear answer (not easy to do!)

Comment: Just to test my understanding: 'li' is an allomorph of 'ly' then? That's what tripped me...

Comment: Yes. We don't normally have the vowel form of "y" in the middle of words, so it becomes "i".